# Accessing Shoeboxed API with Google Apps Script (OAuth v2)

Tags: api, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to initiate a session with the Shoeboxed API via Google Apps Script. I hoped I could use Apps Script internal library to access it but I'm having issues. Here is my attempt:

```
function testAPI() {
var consumerKey = '';
var consumerSecret = '';

var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService('shoeboxed');
oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl(
'https://id.shoeboxed.com/oauth/token');
oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl(
'https://id.shoeboxed.com/oauth/token');
oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl(
'https://id.shoeboxed.com/oauth/authorize');
oauthConfig.setConsumerKey(consumerKey);
oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);

var options = {
  'oAuthServiceName' : 'shoeboxed',
  'oAuthUseToken' : 'always'
};

var url = 'https://api.shoeboxed.com/v2/user';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
Logger.log("Response: " + response.getContentText());
}
```

It's failing at the point where it attempts to fetch user data via the API url with an authorization failed message. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Information about the API and OAuth can be found here: https://github.com/Shoeboxed/api/blob/master/sections/authentication.md

Comment: http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/oauthtoo/ezyoauth2

Answer (score 1):

### New method:

It looks like that API requires OAuth2, but the UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService method only works with the older version of OAuth.

There's a new method [ScriptApp.newStateToken()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newStateToken()) which can be used in combination with OAuth2, but it requires more manual/explicit control over the OAuth2 steps. It generates a `state` token.

### A minor detail on that method:

Note that when you construct URLs, the `state` token should passed as a URL parameter on the `.../authorize` URL, not embedded as a URL parameter within the `.../usercallback` URL.

For example:

You would want to redirect the user to:

```
https://id.shoeboxed.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=<your client id>&response_type=code&scope=all&redirect_uri=<your site>&state=<CSRF token>
```

where `redirect_uri` is:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/d/1234567890abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz/usercallback
```

When the user clicked authorize,  Shoeboxed should redirect them to:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/d/1234567890abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz/usercallback?state=<CSRF token>
```

Answer (score 0):

oauth2 support for the shoeboxd API has just been added to the cEzyOauth2 Google Apps Script library.

You can copy the pattern to your app and [include the library as described here](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/oauthtoo/shoeboxd)

It uses the statetoken as described by Steve Lieberman, and takes care of the oauth2 conversation, token handling and refreshing automatically.